# found easter egg (incl releasing trigger) in as code, but no clue how to fire it

Tags: disassembly, flash

I've been recently looking through decompiled AS3 code from Ubisoft's "The Settlers Online" and found an easter egg along with something that looked like trigger, but - as I have never read AS3 before, and even if - decompiled code is often too obscure to understand, even for experienced coders , not to say for me. so, here I came up with question: anyone has a clue how to trigger that easter contained in this tiny AS3 snippet:

```
package Utils
{
   import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
   import flash.ui.Keyboard;
   import mx.core.UIComponent;

   public class RabbidCode
   {


      private var sequence:Array;

      public function RabbidCode()
      {
         while(true)
         {
            while(true)
            {
               switch(0)
               {
                  case 0:
                     super();
                     this.reset();
                     (global.getApplication() as UIComponent).stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP,this.handleKeyUp);
                     return;
                  case 1:
                     continue;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      private function handleKeyUp(param1:KeyboardEvent) : void
      {
         while(false)
         {
         }
         var _loc2_:int = this.sequence.shift();
         if(param1.keyCode == _loc2_)
         {
            if(this.sequence.length == 0)
            {
               this.action();
            }
            else
            {
               return;
            }
         }
         this.reset();
      }

      private function action() : void
      {
         while(true)
         {
            while(true)
            {
               switch(0)
               {
                  case 0:
                     var _loc1_:* = ["Graubart","Pandur","Amaris","Helene","Ravel","EnglishFellow","Shark","AJ","David","Ferhat","Kalle","Buan","Franck","Alexandra","Bine","Nils","ZockenMitKatze","Aenlin","Miriam","Crystaliq","Buddy","Céline","Ally","Jason","Omris","Orowa","Lyedra","Anna","Talamira","Taku","Throril","Naknaknak","Infran","Linki","Henning","Dzan","Sandra","Pherlin","Andreas","Alexander","Angel","Bogdan","Carlos","Chris","Claudiu","Denis","Ignacio","Linda","Marcel","Matthias","Michael","Mirco","Oliver","Paul","Catalin","Bob","Rudi","Ruslan","Simon","Sonja","Stefan","Tobias","Jakub","Violeta","Maggie","Clara","Erkan","Sabrina","Sebastian","Patrick","Aeyline","Penelopa","Ondgrund","Belegha","Acadma","Omris","Amta","Maxhylere","Kumakun","Orowa","Saqui","Nanuq","Taku","Aylea","Anash","Zoltan","Grubur","Veythyru"];
                     global.ui.mCurrentPlayerZone.mSettlerKIManager.setNameList(_loc1_);
                     return;
                  case 1:
                     continue;
               }
            }
         }
      }

      private function reset() : void
      {
         while(false)
         {
         }
         this.sequence = [Keyboard.UP,Keyboard.UP,Keyboard.DOWN,Keyboard.DOWN,Keyboard.LEFT,Keyboard.RIGHT,Keyboard.LEFT,Keyboard.RIGHT,"B".charCodeAt(0),"A".charCodeAt(0)];
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This combination (<kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>up</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>down</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>right</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>B</kbd>) is a well known [Konami code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konami_Code) so just pressing those keys should trigger it.

The real question here is when, or if at all this code is loaded so that it actually is hooked-up and can be triggered.